# How can I convert versicolor to 0 and virginica to 1

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

I want this array to convert Versicolor to 0 and Virginica to 1 because I want to classify iris dataset using logistic regression. Could you give me some help???

```
import csv
import numpy as np
with open('./iris.csv', 'r') as f:
    data_iter = csv.reader(f)
    data = [data for data in data_iter]
iris = np.asarray(data)
x= iris[51:-1, [1,2]]

y= iris[51:-1,[4]]
```

Comment: please , paste array here as a text or code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with a 1D array named `y`:

```py
new_y = np.char.replace(y, 'Versicolor', 0)
new_y = np.char.replace(new_y, 'Virginica', 1)
```